When a tag is removed, why isn't it removed from watchlists?
Recent activity in New Caledonia (and the closure of the airport) made me wonder if there were any recent questions in the air-calin tag on Travel. It's one of my watched tags, so I clicked it and -- there were no questions at all. In fact, it's no longer a tag. Now the reasons for that are out of scope for this question. I just wonder if it's possible to remove tags from watchlists when they aren't tags any more. Or perhaps highlight the button in the watched tags area in some way that indicates something has happened.
This is not only about keeping my "watched tags" area clear of clutter: if someone has quietly removed a tag from all the questions that were using it, that's the sort of thing someone should notice and perhaps evaluate - and who better than people who care enough about that topic to watch that tag?

I wonder how something like this would interact with the input being intentionally freeform; e.g. I have [status-*] in my watched tag list on meta, which isn't a tag name, in order to watch all the status tags at once. I do really like the idea of being notified somehow that a watched tag has gone away, though.

I don't really think it is a feature request

it would be a feature to add code to the process of tag deleting, or to the process of watched-tag-loading-and-displaying.

It is sometimes useful to follow untagged, which is special.

that would let me see questions that had lost their only tag. But not tags that have been removed from questions (leaving others behind) or used on questions that have been removed, leading to the tag itself disappearing. For example, I don't really know why the air-calin tag is gone: the airline still exists. People asked questions related to it at one point. Are those questions gone? I don't know. But I might have noticed whatever happened sooner, if there had been some UI about it.
